# Using bootstrap 3, how do you have a completely different navbar for mobile rather than responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building my webapp and I dont like the way my navbar looks when collapses. I'd rather just have a different navbar for mobile users and basically any browser that falls below the width threshold.

So rather than how bootstrap just turns your navbar into a list, I'd rather make it look nice with clickable icons.

What's the best way of going about this? Here's my current navbar.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

      <div class="navbar-header">


          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <div {{action toggleProperty "showNotifications"}}  id="not-container-mobile" class="navbar-toggle" style="position:relative">
            <i
               class="icon-globe icon-large use-blue"></i>         

               {{#if showNotifications}}
               {{view App.NotificationView}}
               {{/if}}
          </div>
          <a class="navbar-brand " href="#"><img class="logo"
             src="/images/app_dark.png"></a>
      </div>




<div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
      <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" >

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
          <div {{action toggleProperty "showNotifications"}} id="not-container"  style="position:relative">
            <i
               class="icon-globe icon-large use-blue"></i>         

               {{#if showNotifications}}
               {{view App.NotificationView}}
               {{/if}}
          </div>
      </li>
        <li>{{view App.SearchView}}</li>

        <li>
        <div class="navbar-header navbar-right">
              <p class="navbar-text">
              {{#link-to "user" currentUser._id.$oid}}
              {{currentUser.name}}
              {{/link-to}}

              </p>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li>
        <div id="settings-cog" class="navbar-header navbar-right">
           <li  class="dropdown">
              <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">          
                 <i class="icon-cogs icon-large use-blue"></i>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#changePassModal" href="#">Change Password</a></li>
                 <li><a {{action "toggleEditView" target="base"}} data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editModal" href="#" href="#">Edit Profile</a></li>
                 <li><a href="/#/logout">Logout</a></li>
              </ul>
           </li>
        </div>
        </li>

        </ul>

        </div>
        </div>



        </div>


</nav>
```

Comment: can change styles any way you want using css media queries

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just create two navbars. On your full-sized navbar add the classes `.hidden-sm` and `.hidden-xs`. Then, on your mobile navbar add the classes `.visible-xs` and `.visible-sm`. That way, you only see the navbar for the sizes you've designated. For more options, see [Responsive utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities).